# Three.js Points with multiple textures

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am working on a Three.js scene in which I'd like to use many points with different textures. However, so far I haven't been able to change textures in my fragment shader. Despite the fact that the points in the following scene should alternate between texture 0 (a cat) and 1 (a dog), all points show the same texture:

```js
/**
* Generate a scene object with a background color
**/

function getScene() {
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xaaaaaa);
  return scene;
}

/**
* Generate the camera to be used in the scene. Camera args:
*   [0] field of view: identifies the portion of the scene
*     visible at any time (in degrees)
*   [1] aspect ratio: identifies the aspect ratio of the
*     scene in width/height
*   [2] near clipping plane: objects closer than the near
*     clipping plane are culled from the scene
*   [3] far clipping plane: objects farther than the far
*     clipping plane are culled from the scene
**/

function getCamera() {
  var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 1, -6000);
  return camera;
}

/**
* Generate the renderer to be used in the scene
**/

function getRenderer() {
  // Create the canvas with a renderer
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  // Add support for retina displays
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  // Specify the size of the canvas
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  // Add the canvas to the DOM
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  return renderer;
}

/**
* Generate the controls to be used in the scene
* @param {obj} camera: the three.js camera for the scene
* @param {obj} renderer: the three.js renderer for the scene
**/

function getControls(camera, renderer) {
  var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
  controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
  return controls;
}

/**
* Generate the points for the scene
* @param {obj} scene: the current scene object
**/

function addPoints(scene) {
  // this geometry builds a blueprint and many copies of the blueprint
  var geometry  = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();

  geometry.addAttribute( 'position',
    new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( [0, 0, 0] ), 3));

  // add data for each observation
  var n = 10000; // number of observations
  var translation = new Float32Array( n * 3 );
  var texture = new Float32Array( n );
  var translationIterator = 0;

  for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    texture[i] = i % 2;
  }

  for (var i=0; i<n*3; i++) {
    switch (translationIterator % 3) {
      case 0:
        translation[translationIterator++] = ((i * 50) % 10000) - 5000;
        break;
      case 1:
        translation[translationIterator++] = Math.floor((i / 160) * 50) - 5000;
        break;
      case 2:
        translation[translationIterator++] = 10;
        break;
    }
  }

  geometry.addAttribute( 'translation',
    new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( translation, 3, 1 ) );

  geometry.addAttribute( 'textureIndex',
    new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( texture, 1, 1 ) );

  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  var material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      textures: {
        'type': 'tv',
        'value': [
          loader.load('https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/tsne-webgl/assets/cat.jpg'),
          loader.load('https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/tsne-webgl/assets/dog.jpg'),
        ],
      }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent,
  });
  var mesh = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
  mesh.frustumCulled = false; // prevent the mesh from being clipped on drag
  scene.add(mesh);
}

/**
* Render!
**/

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  controls.update();
};

/**
* Main
**/

var scene = getScene();
var camera = getCamera();
var renderer = getRenderer();
var controls = getControls(camera, renderer);
addPoints(scene);
render();
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://rawgit.com/YaleDHLab/pix-plot/master/assets/js/trackball-controls.js'></script>

    <script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
    /**
    * The vertex shader's main() function must define `gl_Position`,
    * which describes the position of each vertex in screen coordinates.
    *
    * To do so, we can use the following variables defined by Three.js:
    *   attribute vec3 position - stores each vertex's position in world space
    *   attribute vec2 uv - sets each vertex's the texture coordinates
    *   uniform mat4 projectionMatrix - maps camera space into screen space
    *   uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix - combines:
    *     model matrix: maps a point's local coordinate space into world space
    *     view matrix: maps world space into camera space
    *
    * `attributes` can vary from vertex to vertex and are defined as arrays
    *   with length equal to the number of vertices. Each index in the array
    *   is an attribute for the corresponding vertex. Each attribute must
    *   contain n_vertices * n_components, where n_components is the length
    *   of the given datatype (e.g. for a vec2, n_components = 2; for a float,
    *   n_components = 1)
    * `uniforms` are constant across all vertices
    * `varyings` are values passed from the vertex to the fragment shader
    *
    * For the full list of uniforms defined by three, see:
    *   https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram
    **/

    // set float precision
    precision mediump float;

    // specify geometry uniforms
    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

    // to get the camera attributes:
    uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

    // blueprint attributes
    attribute vec3 position; // sets the blueprint's vertex positions

    // instance attributes
    attribute vec3 translation; // x y translation offsets for an instance
    attribute float textureIndex; // idx of texture in sampler

    // specify the varyings to pass to instances
    varying float vTextureIndex;

    void main() {
      // pass varyings to fragment shader
      //vTextureIndex = textureIndex;

      // set point position
      vec3 pos = position + translation;
      vec4 projected = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
      gl_Position = projected;

      // use the delta between the point position and camera position to size point
      float xDelta = pow(projected[0] - cameraPosition[0], 2.0);
      float yDelta = pow(projected[1] - cameraPosition[1], 2.0);
      float zDelta = pow(projected[2] - cameraPosition[2], 2.0);
      float delta  = pow(xDelta + yDelta + zDelta, 0.5);
      gl_PointSize = 50000.0 / delta;
    }
    </script>

    <script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
    /**
    * The fragment shader's main() function must define `gl_FragColor`,
    * which describes the pixel color of each pixel on the screen.
    *
    * To do so, we can use uniforms passed into the shader and varyings
    * passed from the vertex shader.
    *
    * Attempting to read a varying not generated by the vertex shader will
    * throw a warning but won't prevent shader compiling.
    **/

    precision highp float;

    uniform sampler2D textures[2];

    // declare received varyings
    varying float vTextureIndex; // instance uv offsets

    void main() {
      int texIdx = int(vTextureIndex);
      vec2 uv = vec2(0.0, 0.0) + vec2( gl_PointCoord.x, 1.0 - gl_PointCoord.y );
      if (texIdx == 0) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(textures[0], uv );
      } else if (texIdx == 1) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(textures[1], uv );
      }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone see what I'm missing? I'd be very grateful for any insight others can offer on this question!

Comment: Can you try to change just the color? In other words, if `texIdx` is `0`, make the point `RED`, and if it's `1`, make it `BLUE`. That will validate that your per-point indexing is working how you expect.

Comment: Sure thing, we just need to do: `if (texIdx == 0) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
      } else if (texIdx == 1) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
      }` But all the points are red. It's like a bad Momma's and the Poppa's song. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: Well, the obvious thing is that `texIdx` is always evaluating as `0`. You could change your logic to evaluate `vTextureIndex` directly to see if _that_ is what you think it is--`if(vTextureIndex < 0.5){ red } else if(vTextureIndex < 1.5) { green } else...`.

Comment: Oh good grief I had commented out the varying in the fragment shader.

Comment: @TheJim01 I found the real problem -- if one reads from an attribute that isn't passed into the vertex shader, the value of that attribute is set to 0 for some reason, and this is why my real texture indices weren't updating. Reading an attribute that's not passed to the vertex shader really ought to throw an error or warning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case others end up here facing the same trouble I had, I wanted to say that the above example was a simplified version of a larger scene. In that other scene, I was passing in an attribute `texture` **but I was initializing the attribute as `textureIndex`** inside the vertex shader. I then passed the textureIndex to the fragment shader as a varying, where it always equalled 0. So the moral of the story is -- if you try to read from an attribute that isn't passed to the vertex shader, that value evidently equates to zero. It would be great if this threw an error instead.

In the silly example above I had commented out the varying declaration in the fragment shader. This is fixed:

```js
  /**
  * Generate a scene object with a background color
  **/

  function getScene() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xaaaaaa);
    return scene;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the camera to be used in the scene. Camera args:
  *   [0] field of view: identifies the portion of the scene
  *     visible at any time (in degrees)
  *   [1] aspect ratio: identifies the aspect ratio of the
  *     scene in width/height
  *   [2] near clipping plane: objects closer than the near
  *     clipping plane are culled from the scene
  *   [3] far clipping plane: objects farther than the far
  *     clipping plane are culled from the scene
  **/

  function getCamera() {
    var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(0, 1, -6000);
    return camera;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the renderer to be used in the scene
  **/

  function getRenderer() {
    // Create the canvas with a renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    // Add support for retina displays
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    // Specify the size of the canvas
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add the canvas to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    return renderer;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the controls to be used in the scene
  * @param {obj} camera: the three.js camera for the scene
  * @param {obj} renderer: the three.js renderer for the scene
  **/

  function getControls(camera, renderer) {
    var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
    controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
    return controls;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the points for the scene
  * @param {obj} scene: the current scene object
  **/

  function addPoints(scene) {
    // this geometry builds a blueprint and many copies of the blueprint
    var geometry  = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();

    geometry.addAttribute( 'position',
      new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( [0, 0, 0] ), 3));

    // add data for each observation
    var n = 10000; // number of observations
    var translation = new Float32Array( n * 3 );
    var texture = new Float32Array( n );
    var translationIterator = 0;

    for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
      texture[i] = i % 2;
    }

    for (var i=0; i<n*3; i++) {
      switch (translationIterator % 3) {
        case 0:
          translation[translationIterator++] = ((i * 50) % 10000) - 5000;
          break;
        case 1:
          translation[translationIterator++] = Math.floor((i / 160) * 50) - 5000;
          break;
        case 2:
          translation[translationIterator++] = 10;
          break;
      }
    }

    geometry.addAttribute( 'translation',
      new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( translation, 3, 1 ) );

    geometry.addAttribute( 'textureIndex',
      new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( texture, 1, 1 ) );

    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: {
        textures: {
          'type': 'tv',
          'value': [
            loader.load('https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/tsne-webgl/assets/cat.jpg'),
            loader.load('https://s3.amazonaws.com/duhaime/blog/tsne-webgl/assets/dog.jpg'),
          ],
        }
      },
      vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
      fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent,
    });
    var mesh = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
    mesh.frustumCulled = false; // prevent the mesh from being clipped on drag
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  /**
  * Render!
  **/

  function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    controls.update();
  };

  /**
  * Main
  **/

  var scene = getScene();
  var camera = getCamera();
  var renderer = getRenderer();
  var controls = getControls(camera, renderer);
  addPoints(scene);
  render();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #000; }
  body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
  canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://rawgit.com/YaleDHLab/pix-plot/master/assets/js/trackball-controls.js'></script>

    <script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
    /**
    * The vertex shader's main() function must define `gl_Position`,
    * which describes the position of each vertex in screen coordinates.
    *
    * To do so, we can use the following variables defined by Three.js:
    *   attribute vec3 position - stores each vertex's position in world space
    *   attribute vec2 uv - sets each vertex's the texture coordinates
    *   uniform mat4 projectionMatrix - maps camera space into screen space
    *   uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix - combines:
    *     model matrix: maps a point's local coordinate space into world space
    *     view matrix: maps world space into camera space
    *
    * `attributes` can vary from vertex to vertex and are defined as arrays
    *   with length equal to the number of vertices. Each index in the array
    *   is an attribute for the corresponding vertex. Each attribute must
    *   contain n_vertices * n_components, where n_components is the length
    *   of the given datatype (e.g. for a vec2, n_components = 2; for a float,
    *   n_components = 1)
    * `uniforms` are constant across all vertices
    * `varyings` are values passed from the vertex to the fragment shader
    *
    * For the full list of uniforms defined by three, see:
    *   https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram
    **/

    // set float precision
    precision mediump float;

    // specify geometry uniforms
    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

    // to get the camera attributes:
    uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

    // blueprint attributes
    attribute vec3 position; // sets the blueprint's vertex positions

    // instance attributes
    attribute vec3 translation; // x y translation offsets for an instance
    attribute float textureIndex; // idx of texture in sampler

    // specify the varyings to pass to instances
    varying float vTextureIndex;

    void main() {
      // pass varyings to fragment shader
      vTextureIndex = textureIndex;

      // set point position
      vec3 pos = position + translation;
      vec4 projected = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
      gl_Position = projected;

      // use the delta between the point position and camera position to size point
      float xDelta = pow(projected[0] - cameraPosition[0], 2.0);
      float yDelta = pow(projected[1] - cameraPosition[1], 2.0);
      float zDelta = pow(projected[2] - cameraPosition[2], 2.0);
      float delta  = pow(xDelta + yDelta + zDelta, 0.5);
      gl_PointSize = 50000.0 / delta;
    }
    </script>

    <script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
    /**
    * The fragment shader's main() function must define `gl_FragColor`,
    * which describes the pixel color of each pixel on the screen.
    *
    * To do so, we can use uniforms passed into the shader and varyings
    * passed from the vertex shader.
    *
    * Attempting to read a varying not generated by the vertex shader will
    * throw a warning but won't prevent shader compiling.
    **/

    precision highp float;

    uniform sampler2D textures[2];

    // declare received varyings
    varying float vTextureIndex; // instance uv offsets

    void main() {
      int texIdx = int(vTextureIndex);
      vec2 uv = vec2(0.0, 0.0) + vec2( gl_PointCoord.x, 1.0 - gl_PointCoord.y );
      if (texIdx == 0) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(textures[0], uv );
      } else if (texIdx == 1) {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(textures[1], uv );
      }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```